# Incremental import- To avoid duplication of rows

Tags: sqoop

Consider a table departments with below data-

```
ID -1,2,3,8000
Name- A,B,C,D
```

I imported data into HDFS using sqoop

Added 2 new rows with ID 4 and 5 into MySQL
Performed incremental import with last value as 3 and mode=append

Data imported has two rows for 8000 ID as the condition used is department_id>3
How can I tweak the below command to make sure duplicate rows are created.

```
sqoop import 
    --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" 
    --username=retail_dba 
    --password=cloudera 
    --table departments 
    --target-dir/user/cloudera/dep1
    --append
    --check-column "department_id"
    --incremental append
    --last-value 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not tweak this command.

`--incremental append` is for appending new data with `--check-column` > `-last-value`.

---

For your usecase you should use `--incremental lastmodified`.

`--check-column` should be of date, time, datetime and timestamp data types.

If you added new records after `--last-value`, it will fetch all the records *(new or updated)*

Sample command:

```
 sqoop import 
    --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
    --username=retail_dba \
    --password=cloudera \
    --table departments \
    --target-dir/user/cloudera/dep1 \
    --incremental lastmodified \
    --check-column last_update_date \
    --last-value "2015-10-20 06:00:01"
```

All the records added after `"2015-10-20 06:00:01"` will be imported.

Check sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports) for more details.

Comment: The last_update_date column is not present in the table.

Comment: The last_update_date is not present in the table. Hence We cannot use it i believe.

Comment: @VarunJoshi you have to create date or timestamp  column in the table to use `--incremental lastmodified`